# How to insert Credentials in PhotosLibrarySettings object on Android mobile App. Using Google Sign-In

Tags: java, android, google-signin, google-photos

I do not know how to pass Credentials to Google Photos Library API, after user has authenticated with Google Sign-In, and has been authorized to use Google Photos Library API.

I am developing a mobile App (no backend server, just installed Android App). The goal is that user:

1. authenticates (with a google account)
2. authorizes the App to use Google Photos Library
3. manage photos.

Points 1 and 2 are ok in my project. To do them I use Google Sign-In. Everything works. But point 3 does not work: I do not know how to insert credentials within the PhotosLibrarySetting object:

PhotosLibrarySettings settings = PhotosLibrarySettings.newBuilder()
     .setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create("add credentials here").build();

I have tried to insert the "credentials json" file, like

GoogleCredentials.fromStream(getAssets().open("system" + File.separator + "credentials.json"))

but only works with a Service Account Key (in the Google API Console) and I do not have it. I just have 2 Credentials created in my Google API Console: one oAuthClientID for Android, and one oAuthClientID for Web Client (Auto-created for Google Sign-In). And downloading both json credentials of these last Clients ID, does not work.

I have also tried to use the Token retrieved from GoogleSignInOptions (getIdToken function) after authenticate and authorize with GoogleSignIn, like this:

// acc is the object corresponding to user account

AccessToken tken = new AccessToken(acc.getIdToken(), new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()+3000000));
GoogleCredentials.newBuilder().setAccessToken(tken).build()))

but I receive an error:

UNAUTHENTICATED: Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.

Comment: did you find answer? I have similar problem.

Comment: I have similar problem too. Did u find a solution?